# selecting partial text with setsrat and setEnd

Tags: javascript, html, range

I am trying to select the text `some` from text in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vZ2fF/ but it does not seem to be working at all... what am I doing wrong???

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p id="ul1">
        <span id="span1">some element</span>
        <span>some element2</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

```
var selection1= window.getSelection();

var range1=document.createRange();
var ul= document.getElementById("ul1");

var idspan=document.getElementById("span1");

range1.setStart(idspan, 0);
range1.setEnd(idspan, 5);

selection1.addRange(range1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/lizoh/1/edit)**

```
var Win = window, Doc = document;
var selection1 = Win.getSelection ? Win.getSelection() : Doc.selection.createRange();
var range = Doc.createRange();

function El(id){ return Doc.getElementById(id); }
var ul = El("ul1");
var idspan = El("span1").firstChild; // Note the Node element

range.setStart(idspan, 0);
range.setEnd(idspan, 4);

selection1.addRange(range);
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range.setStart
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range.setEnd
https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-range-setstart

Comment: I did this before too but was not working.. now its working :o

Comment: @user2638682 I'm glad it works now :) I created the `El` function just to simplify elements grab, any way you should test the above in IE9 also, probably you'd need some more tweaks! Happy coding

Comment: Can I do it this way... `ul.firstChild.firstChild`

Comment: @user2638682 `ul.childNodes.item(1).firstChild;`

Answer (score 1):

That is because, `setEnd`'s second argument `endOffset` is the number of child nodes between the start of the `endNode`.

So, your `idspan` has only one child node that is `textnode`. So it will not work for `range1.setEnd(idspan,5)`. For that, you need to have 5 child elements.

This will work: `range1.setEnd(idspan,1)`, since the number of child nodes in `idspan` is just one (ie textnode).